# Binary Analysis Tool (BAT) no longer maintained - alternatives?

Tags: firmware, tools, unpacking

I read on the BAT [github](https://github.com/armijnhemel/binaryanalysis) page that BAT is no longer actively maintained.

- Why did the project come to an end?
- What alternatives are there to unpack all kinds of archives /
  firmwares / binary structures?
- Or do you plan to still use BAT nevertheless?